# JS function which can work with 2 different invocations.

Tags: javascript

How to define a function lets say 'add' in Javascript, that will support both of these invocations.

add(5,6) 
or
add(5)(6)

both giving the same output, which is 11.

Comment: The second version looks like it is returning a function that adds five to whatever is passed to it.

Comment: Check the number of arguments. Return a function when there's only one.

Comment: @DavidThomas Not if you return a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function add(a, b)
    if (typeof(b) === "undefined") {
        return function (b) { return a + b; };
    }
    return a + b;
}
```

or, the logical extension:

```
function add(a, b)
    if (typeof(b) === "undefined") {
        return function (b) { return a + b; };
    }
    return add(a)(b);
}
```